# Typescript: For in loop over objects won't recognise object's properties

Tags: angular, typescript, properties, for-in-loop

I'm using a `for in` to loop over a list of Meeting-objects called `allMeetings`. This loop is filling another list called `allEvents`, where objects other than Meeting will end up in. In that loop I'm trying to get the properties of the Meeting object, but they aren't recognised. I wonder how to solve or bypass it.

*My Meeting model*:

```
export class Meeting {
    id: UUID;
    date: Date;
    description: string;
}
```

*The TS-File*: 
*The loop is used in the `makeEvents()` method*

```
...
import { Meeting } from '../models/meeting.model';
import { MeetingsService } from '../services/meetings.service';
...
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    allEvents: SpikesEvent[] = undefined;
    allMeetings: Meeting[] = undefined;

   constructor(private _meetingsService: MeetingsService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadMeetings();
        this.makeEvents();
    }

    loadMeetings(): void {
        this._meetingsService.getAllMeetings().subscribe(
            (allMeetings: Meeting[]) => {
                this.allMeetings = allMeetings;
            }
        );
    }

    makeEvents(): void {
        for (let meeting in this.allMeetings) {
            this.allEvents.push({
                start: startOfDay(meeting.date),
                title: meeting.description,
                color: colors.yellowsunflower,
                type: "meeting",
                id: meeting.id,
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**So, date, description and id of meeting aren't recognised.**

EDIT 1: Added the constructor in the TS-File. 
EDIT 2: I'm retrieving my data from rethinkDB so there's no JSON-file but here's a log to prove that the Meeting object is in fact not empty:

```
date: "Fri Feb 20 1993 00:00:00 GMT+00:00", description: "meeting about dummy data", id: "088c0baf-3c02-48b2-a072-65905fb0c0a7"
```

Comment: makeEvents() is called before loadMeetings() has finished running. So you dont have the data inside allMeetings object within makeEvents()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Comment: @Amit Chigadani - It's true that I still have to think about asynchronous programming when executing my code but the problem is that I can't read the property's of the Meeting-object.

Comment: @WouterVanherck that's because `meeting` is `undefined` inside `makeEvents` method. Check the links to find out why.

Comment: Yes you won't, because you have not injected the Meeting class in your component. Add this `constructor(private allMeetings: Meeting){}`. Add all the dependency injections properly. I might have missed few here.

Comment: @Amit Chigadani - Whoops, forgot to include it in the question (but it was in my code)

Comment: Can you share your `allmeetings` json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny, everyone has missed the fact that you are iterating a list of objects with [for ...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and trying to use the key as the object itself.

That is why TypeScript "won't recognize" it's properties. If you want to use for-in:

```
for (let meeting in this.allMeetings) {
    this.allEvents.push({
        start: startOfDay(this.allMeetings[meeting].date),
        //...
    });
}
```

I'd rather use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

The other answer about the asynchronous code is still valid for runtime execution though, but that is not the problem you are asking about here.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that my problem is **not** related to the asynchronous topic.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadMeetings();
}

loadMeetings(): void {
    this._meetingsService.getAllMeetings().subscribe(
        (allMeetings: Meeting[]) => {
            this.allMeetings = allMeetings;
            // you should call this function once 
            // we get the data in this.allMeetings
            this.makeEvents();
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry if my question isn't clear enough. I'm not yet thinking about asynchronous programming and am just wondering why typeScript doesn't recognise the properties. Or are these related?

Comment: @Wouter Vanherck Yes they are related, declaring an object with some class will not give you the prototype of the class itself. So definitely meeting variable within for loop will be undefined, because allMeetings object itself will be undefined before your observable returns

Comment: Tried it the way you did but that didn't change the fact that `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'string'` came up, including the errors for the other properties.

Comment: in Meeting class change id:number to string or change this id: parseInt (meeting.id).

Comment: @VivekDoshi a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format) is represented as a string so don't worry about changing it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manipulate the data inside the callback, like suggested. Here's a useful question to look at: [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

As also mentioned you are using the key as the object instead, as suggested, use `forEach` instead. So first execute `loadMeetings` and inside the callback call `makeEvents`:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadMeetings();
}

loadMeetings(): void {
   this._meetingsService.getAllMeetings()
     .subscribe((allMeetings: Meeting[]) => {
         this.allMeetings = allMeetings;
            this.makeEvents();
        });
}
```

Then your `makeEvents` would look like this:

```ts
makeEvents(): void {
  this.allMeetings.forEach((x:Meeting) => {
     this.allEvents.push({
       start: startOfDay(x.date),
       title: x.description,
       color: colors.yellowsunflower,
       type: "meeting",
       id: x.id,
     })
  })
}
```

Then it should work as you want, here's a

### [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/vpe38e5S4JUs1uP9BIei?p=preview)

Comment: By elaborating @Alex 's answer on how to use the foreach you've helped me, thanks for that.

Comment: No problem! Wanted to just lift up the issue that your `allMeetings` would be undefined/empty at the point when you try and execute `makeEvents` as your code sits now, which would cause additional issue. But yes, that was not perhaps your main question at hand. Most important you got a solution for your problem :) Have a great day and happy coding! :)